# MSVC 2019: "the size of an array must be greater than zero"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, migration

I have migrated a (working) older project into MSVC 2019 using its .dsw file.
That appeared to go fine but I get the error message (shown in title) upon build.
The error occurred in "winnt.h".
Note: I have not declared any zero-length arrays.
**How do I fix this?**

Comment: You should (i) add a language tag, presumably C or C++, (ii) copy the complete error message including the line number, (iii) post the minimal code that triggers it.

Comment: Solved: See Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the *completely misleading* error message, the problem has nothing to do with a zero-size array. Rather it is a struct packing issue.  To fix this:

**Solution #1**

Add the following line before including windows.h

```
  #define WINDOWS_IGNORE_PACKING_MISMATCH
  #include <windows.h>
```

**Solution #2**

Change the packing in your project using
Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> CodeGeneration ->
Struct Member Alignment = "8 Bytes"